# Cannot change the date format to the first record

Tags: google-sheets-query

Data are captured from Google Form and the first column is the Timestamp, I want to query it and only show all unique date for further use.

Formula

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:A, "SELECT A format A 'dd-mmm-yyyy'", 1)
```

only the first record cannot be formatted, is it a bug or something wrong to my formula? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the header argument '1'.

**Query should look likes this:**

```
=unique(QUERY(A2:A, "SELECT A format A 'dd-mmm-yyyy'"))
```

**Here is working result:**

[image]